# A proof about polynomial division

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Suppose $g(x)=ax+b$,$a,b\in K$,$K$ is a field, and $f(x)\in K[x]$, prove:
>   $$g(x)|f^2(x)\Leftrightarrow g(x)|f(x)$$

The $\Leftarrow$ part is so trivial. But for the $\Rightarrow$ part I get stuck.
I feel that I may need to discuss it in separate cases, and for 
case 1: where $a=b=0$;
case 2: where $a=0,b\ne0$.
The proof is trivial, but I don't know how to get about tackling
case 3: where $a\ne0$.
I know $g(x)|f^2(x)$ means $\exists ! q(x)\in K[x]$ s.t. $f^2(x)=q(x)(ax+b)$, which yields $2\deg f(x)=1+\deg q(x)$, thus $q(x)$ is an odd number and $\ge1$. 
And to show $g(x)|f(x)$ means showing $\exists !p(x)\in K[x]$ s.t. $f(x)=p(x)(ax+b)$. 
But I don't know how to proceed since I fail to see any connection between the two.
Really need some help here. I'll appreciate any help or hint. Best regards!

Comment: Are there any additional hypothesis you have left out? For instance, take g(x)=f(x)^2. Then g(x) divides f(x)^2 but not f(x).

Comment: If $f(x)$ has only irreducible factors of degree $2$ or more, then $g(x)$ cannot possibly divide $f^2(x)$.

Comment: @bburGsamohT. Deg g(x) is at most one. So g(x)=f^2(x) means g(x) and f(x) both constant. Isn't it trivial?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Evaluate $\ f^2  = (ax\!+\!b) q\ $ at a root of $\, ax\! +\! b\,$ to deduce that the root is also a root of $\,f,\,$ so $\,ax\!+\!b\mid f\,$ by the Factor Theorem,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How one solves the problem depends on the machinery already available.

For example, in the case $a\ne 0$ we can argue as follows. We have $ar+b=0$ when $r=-(ba^{-1})$. Thus $f^2(r)=0$, and therefore $f(r)=0$, and therefore $ax+b$ divides $f(x)$ by the Remainder Theorem.

A fancier way is to observe that $ax+b$ is irreducible. Our polynomial ring is a Euclidean domain, so if $ax+b$ divides the product $f(x)f(x)$, it must divide one of the terms.

Comment: Remark that the last paragraph implicitly uses the fact that irreducibles are *prime* in a Euclidean domain, therefore prime $\,g\mid f^2\Rightarrow\, g\mid f.\,$ Or maybe it intends to use some closely related result like Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 3):

Wealll, $K[x]$ is a principal ideal domain, as is widely known; in a PID, irreducibles and primes coincide; $ax + b $ is irreducible in $K[x]$, therefore prime; thus $ax + b \mid (f(x))^2$ implies $ax + b$ divides at least one factor of $(f(x))^2 = f(x)f(x)$, whence $g(x) = ax + b \mid f(x)$.  ***QED.***

Comment: So "K is a PID" is necessary here?

Comment: @Vim:  who are you quoting?  Not I! At least not here.  Please clarify.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly know PID is. It's just I see you mentioned "K[x] is PID" here in your post.

Comment: Perhaps K is a field implies K is PID?

Comment: @Vim:  PID is an acronym, a standard one as far as I know, for "principal ideal domain"; that is, an integral domain in which every ideal is of the form $(p)$, i.e., has one generator.  It is a pretty standard result that in PIDs, primes and irreducibles are the same.  Does this help?  If not, leave a further comment and I can explain more.  Cheers!

Comment: @Vim:  technically, all fields *are* in fact PIDs, but in sort of a trivial sense:  the only ideals in a field $K$ are $\{ 0 \} (0)$ and $K = (1)$, both principal.  The key here is that for any field $K$, $K[x]$ is a PID; this is shown by applying the division algorithm to an element of minimal degree in any ideal $I$ in $K[x]$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll check it out on that wiki page.

Comment: @Vim:  you're more than welcome, glad to help out.  The page may also contain helpful links.  Anyway, any basic book on commutative rings should have all this stuff.  Best of Luck with It!