# $p$ is prime if and only if $p$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, prime-numbers, principal-ideal-domains

Is this proof correct **?**

Let $R$ be a PID. Prove $p\in R$ is prime if and only if $p\in R$ is irreducible.

**Proof:**

$\implies$

Let $p\in R$ and p prime.

Let $ab=p\in\langle p\rangle.$ Thus $p\mid ab$ and $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

w.l.o.g suppose $p\mid a.$ Then $a=kp,$ for some $k\in R$.

$\implies p=ab=kpb \implies p(1-kb)=0 \implies 1-kb=0 \implies b=1 \implies p $ is irreducible.

$\Leftarrow $ (this side of the proof was based on Xam's proof :)

Let D be an euclidean domain and $p\in D$ irreducible.

Let $ab=p\in\langle p\rangle$. Thus $p\mid ab$.

Now if $p$ doesn't divides a, then we have to prove  $p\mid b.$

Suppose $u=px+ay,$ for some $x,y\in D.$

$\implies bu=bpx+bay$

$\implies p\mid bay$ and $p\mid bpx$

$\implies p\mid bu$

As $ub\mid b,$ then $p\mid b$. Therefore $p$ is prime.

Comment: From $1-kb=0$ you can't conclude that $b=1$, but only you can say that $b$ is an unit, and that's suffices to show that $p$ is irreducible. In your other implication, you're assuming something that you don't have, namely you only have the hypothesis $R$ is a PID, not that $R$ is a Euclidean domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irreducibles are prime in a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257955/irreducibles-are-prime-in-a-ufd)

Comment: @Xam but every euclidean domain is a PID

Comment: @user45765 I am not working in a UFD, I am in a PID

Comment: @AnneliseToft true. The only problem is that you have as hypothesis that $R$ is a PID, not the other way around.

Comment: @AnneliseToft If you know PID, then you should know it is UFD.

Comment: @user45765 but what can be true in UFD might not work in PID

Comment: @Xam So after I conclude p is prime in D, I should say 'therefore the result holds in a PID' because it works in euclidean domain which is smaller than PID

Comment: what is PID and UFD???

Comment: @user477343 I don't know how to explain, you better google it.

Comment: @Anneliset. alright then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my first comment, the first implication is essentially right, you just need to change $1-kb=0 \implies b=1$ for $1-kb=0 \implies b\in R^\times$ (here $R^\times$ is the set of units of $R$).

For the other implication, the basic idea is right. We need to show that there is some unit, let's say $u$ such that we can write $u=px+ay$. How do we do this? Here we use the hypothesis that $R$ is a PID. Namely, we consider the ideal $(p,a)$. Since $R$ is a PID, the above ideal is principal, therefore there is some $r\in R$, $r\neq 0$, such that $(r)=(p,a)$. As $p\in (p,a)=(r)$, we deduce that $r\mid p$, but since $p$ is irreducible, then $r$ and $p$ are associates or $r$ is an unit.

If $r$ and $p$ are associates, then as $r\mid a$ we conclude that $p\mid a$, but $p$ doesn't divide $a$, contradiction. Hence $r$ is an unit. Now, as $r\in (r)=(p,a)$, we can write $r=px+ay$. (In other words, we can take $u=r$ as our desired unit).

Comment: Why $r|a?$  and why $p$ doesn't divide $a?$

Comment: @AnneliseToft $p$ doesn't divide $a$ is your hypothesis ("Now if $p$ doesn't divides $a$ ... "). On the other hand, $r\mid a$ by the same argument that shows that $r\mid p$. Think about it.

Comment: oh I wasn't making a relation with the proof above, if $r|a$ then this $a\in (r)$ happens

Comment: @AnneliseToft it really doesn't matter. We can start the proof with the assumption that $p\mid ab$ and $p\not\mid a$, in then prove that necessarily $p\mid b$. $r\mid a\iff a\in (r)$. But, why it happens that $a\in (r)$?

Comment: I don't know. How this ideals $(p,a)$ looks like? I haven't seen it's form. I know how this $(r)$ looks like: $(r)=\{kr:k\in R\}$

Comment: @AnneliseToft $a\in (p,a)=(r)$. That $a\in (p,a)$ should be clear since $a=p\cdot 0+a\cdot 1$. Hence $a\in (r)$. Btw, the general form of the elements of $(p,a)$ is $px+ay$, for some $x,y\in R$.

Comment: @AnneliseToft You may find helpful [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346348/242), which elaborates on earlier points.

Comment: $ub\mid b $ because $ub\mid b \iff b=\lambda ub$ and $\lambda$ can be taken as $\lambda=u^{-1}$?

Comment: @Annet. yes. That's right.

Answer (score 2):

As to the first part of your proof, you have that $kb = 1$, which says that $b$ is a unit, not necessarily $1$. However, you only need $b$ to be a unit, so it's a minor fix.

For the second half, what if your PID is not a Euclidean Domain? You have proved the result holds in Euclidean Domains, but not in PIDs.