# In a UFD if $x$ is irreducible, then $(x)$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I know how to show that if $(x)$ is prime ideal then $x$ irreducible element.

I know the converse is true if the ring is a UFD, but how to show it?

> i.e. in a UFD, if $x$ is irreducible, then $(x)$ is a prime ideal.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257955/irreducibles-are-prime-in-a-ufd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $R$ be a UFD.
Suppose $p$ is an irreducible element of $R$.
In order to show that $p$ is a prime we will show that $(p)$ is a prime ideal of $R$.
We know that $(p) \neq \{0\}$ because an irreducible element is nonzero.
Also $(p) \neq R$ because an irreducible element is not a unit.
Suppose the product $ab$ of two elements $a, b \in R$ is an element of $(p)$.
Then $ab = mp$ for some $m \in R$.

First suppose $m = 0$.
Then $ab = 0$.
Since $R$ is an integral domain then either $a = 0$ or  $b = 0$.
If $a = 0$ then $a \in (p)$ and if $b = 0$ then $b \in (p)$.
This means $(p)$ is a prime ideal and $p$ is prime.

Now suppose $m \neq 0$, but $m$ is a unit.
This means that $mp$ is an associate of $p$.
Then since $a, b \in R$, which is a UFD, then we have
\begin{align*}
a = y_1 \cdots y_r \\
b = x_1 \cdots x_m
\end{align*}
for some irreducibles $y_k, x_l$.
So $$(y_1 \cdots y_r)(x_1 \cdots x_m) = mp$$
By the uniqueness of the product of irreducibles, $mp$ is equal to $y_k$ for some $k$ or $x_l$ for some $l$.
If $mp$ is equal to $y_k$ for some $k$ then $mp\ |\ a$.
If $mp$ is equal to $x_l$ for some $l$ then $mp\ |\ b$.
It follows that $a \in (p)$ or $b \in (p)$ and $(p)$ is a prime ideal.
In either case $p$ is prime in $R$.

Lastly suppose $m \neq 0$ and $m$ is not a unit.
Then since $m,a, b \in R$, which is a UFD, then we have
\begin{align*}
m = z_1 \cdots z_n \\
a = y_1 \cdots y_r \\
b = x_1 \cdots x_m
\end{align*}
for some irreducibles $z_i, y_k, x_l$.
So $$(y_1 \cdots y_r)(x_1 \cdots x_m) = (z_1 \cdots z_n)p$$
By the uniqueness of the product of irreducibles, $p$ or an associate of $p$ is equal to $y_k$ for some $k$ or $x_l$ for some $l$.
If $p$ or an associate of $p$ is equal to $y_k$ for some $k$ then $p\ |\ a$.
If $p$ or an associate of $p$ is equal to $x_l$ for some $l$ then $p\ |\ b$.
It follows that $a \in (p)$ or $b \in (p)$ and $(p)$ is a prime ideal.
In either case $p$ is prime in $R$.

Comment: Most of the answers make great sense to me. Just one point, why the uniqueness implies mp equals to only one element in the product?

Comment: I think you meant “divide”

Comment: Yes I think divide is correct. I guess it is not guaranteed that $mp$ will actually equal one of the individual irreducibles.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R$ be a unique factorization domain.  Let's call two elements in $R$ *associate* if one can be multiplied by a unit to get the other.  This defines an equivalence relation on $R$, and you can easily check that an associate of an irreducible element is irreducible.  Let $P$ be a complete set of representatives of irreducible elements of $R$ under this relation.

Then to say that $R$ is a unique factorization domain is to say that every nonzero element $x$ in $R$ can be written as

$$u_x\prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{x_p}$$

for a unit $u$ and nonnegative integers $x_p$, and that $u_x$ and $x_p$ are uniquely determined.  This is a finite product.

Let's say that an irreducible element $q \in P$ *occurs* in a given element $x$ if $x_q \geq 1$.  Obviously, $q$ divides $x$ if and only if $q$ occurs in $x$.  If $a, b$ are nonzero elements of $R$, we have

$$u_{ab} \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{(ab)_p}= ab =(u_a \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{a_p})(u_b \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{b_p}) = u_au_b \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{a_p + b_p}$$

so by uniqueness, $u_{ab} = u_au_b$ and $a_p + b_p = (ab)_p$ for all $p$.  It follows from here that if an irreducible element in $P$ occurs in a product $ab$, it must occur in either $a$ or $b$.

This shows the elements of $P$ are prime.  But every irreducible element of $R$ is associate to a unique element of $P$, so every irreducible element of $R$ is prime.

What's also interesting is the converse: if in an integral domain, every nonzero element is a product of irreducibles, and if every irreducible is prime, then you are in a unique factorization domain.

Comment: This was really awesome proof! Will you please let me know why '$q$ divides $x$ then $q$ occurs in $x$' holds?

Comment: If $q$ divides a given nonzero $x$, then $qa = x$ for some nonzero $a$.  Writing $$a = u_a \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{a_p}$$ in its unique form, you have $$x = qa  = u_aq^{a_{q}+1}\prod\limits_{\substack{p \in P \\ p \neq q}}p^{a_p}$$ in its unique form.  Since the exponent $x_{q} = a_q+1$ is positive, $q$ occurs in $x$.

Comment: Interesting and compact approach! Can I ask more? What exactly does notation $$u_x\prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{x_p}$$  exactly means ? $P$ is the parition of irreducible elements of $R$ under the equivalence relation "association". And what is the exact meaning of the ' product of each representatives of $P$ ' ?

Comment: The product $u_x \prod\limits_{p \in P} p^{x_p}$ means you multiply $u_x$ and all the elements $p^{x_p}$ together (since all but finitely many of the $x_p$ are $0$, we are actually only multiplying finitely many things together).

Comment: $P$ is a choice of representatives of those equivalence classes.  In other words, for every irreducible element $q$ of $R$, there is a unique $p \in P$ and a unique unit $v \in R$ such that $q = vp$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Take any $ab\in (x)$ and consider the factorisations of $a$, $b$ and $ab$ into irreducible elements.