# Question regarding equivalence of irreducibles and primes in UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am aware that irreducibles and primes are equivalent in PIDS. However, are they equivalent in UFDs?

Would the following reasoning work?

1) Suppose $f$ is irreducible. Then the prime factorization of $f$ must be $f$ itself. Hence $f$ is a prime itself.

2) Suppose $f$ is prime. That is, if $f \mid ab$ then $f \mid a$ or $f \mid b.$ Suppose $f = gh$ such that $g, h$ are not units. Then $f \mid gh.$ If $f \mid g$ then $g = fk$ It follows that $h$ must be a unit. Hence $f$ must be irreducible.

Does this work? So would it follow that in any $k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ for $k$ a field, the principal ideal generated by an irreducible is a prime ideal as $k[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$ is a UFD?

Comment: Any PID is a UFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent in UFDs. Most texts have this fact, and it is also in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element). This is also mentioned in the [section of the UFD article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain#Equivalent_conditions_for_a_ring_to_be_a_UFD).

Prime implies irreducible always. If $p$ is prime and $p=ab$, then $p$ divides one of the things on the right hand side. After you pick which one it divides, you cancel $p$ from both sides and the thing you didn't divide with $p$ is a unit.

The 'hard' part is the other way, that irreducible implies prime in a UFD. (In fact, it is true in just a GCD domain.)

As far as I know, UFD's are defined using factorizations into *irreducible* elements, not usually primes. Assuming that elements have a unique prime factorization trivializes the task, as you noted: if a product of primes equals an irreducible element $r$, then there can only be one prime.

If you use the definition that every element has a factorization into *irreducibles* then you should use one of the numerous existing solutions for this question on the site, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257955/29335).